# How to clear old data in angular

Tags: angular11

I have created timesheet module , here 1st column (3, 3, 3, 3, 3) when ever I entered all it's ok but again when ever I entered 2nd column (5, , , , 5) the three row is not filled me but when ever I submit this it is getting all the rows like this(5,3,3,3,5). i this 1st column data is getting the empty things.

below is payload code:

```
dayListDetail: [{workdate: "2021-11-29", hoursspent: 5}, {workdate: "2021-11-30", hoursspent: 3},…]
0: {workdate: "2021-11-29", hoursspent: 5}
1: {workdate: "2021-11-30", hoursspent: 3}
2: {workdate: "2021-12-01", hoursspent: 3}
3: {workdate: "2021-12-02", hoursspent: 3}
4: {workdate: "2021-12-03", hoursspent: 5}
```

here is Angular code:component.ts file

```
for (var i=0; i<counter; i++){
        dayArr = [];
        if (this.tform.value.timesheet[i].mon != null && this.tform.value.timesheet[i].mon != ''){
          monObj = {
            workdate: arr[0].date, 
            hoursspent: Number(this.tform.value.timesheet[i].mon)
          }
          console.log('Hi');
          console.log(monObj);
        }
        if (this.tform.value.timesheet[i].tue != null && this.tform.value.timesheet[i].tue != ''){
          tueObj = {
            workdate: arr[1].date,
            hoursspent: Number(this.tform.value.timesheet[i].tue)
          }
          console.log(tueObj);
        }
        if (this.tform.value.timesheet[i].wed != null && this.tform.value.timesheet[i].wed != ''){
          wedObj = {
            workdate: arr[2].date,
            hoursspent: Number(this.tform.value.timesheet[i].wed)
          }
          console.log(wedObj);
        }
        if (this.tform.value.timesheet[i].thur != null && this.tform.value.timesheet[i].thur != ''){
          thursObj = {
            workdate: arr[3].date,
            hoursspent: Number(this.tform.value.timesheet[i].thur)
          }
          console.log(thursObj);
        }
        if (this.tform.value.timesheet[i].fri != null && this.tform.value.timesheet[i].fri != ''){
          friObj = {
            workdate: arr[4].date,
            hoursspent: Number(this.tform.value.timesheet[i].fri)
          }
          console.log(friObj);
        }
        dayArr.push(monObj, tueObj, wedObj, thursObj, friObj);
        tmpPayloadObj = {
          timesheetId: this.tform.value.timesheet[i].timesheetId!=undefined?this.tform.value.timesheet[i].timesheetId:0,
          projectid: this.tform.value.timesheet[i].project,
          taskid: this.tform.value.timesheet[i].task,
          dayListDetail: dayArr,
          totalHours: 0
        }
        finalArr.push(tmpPayloadObj)
      }
```